# How do I fix position a div inside a statically positioned div?

Tags: javascript, css, html

My question is about placing a div with position: fixed inside of a div with position: static.

I have a few websites where I fix the header to the top of the window. I also have a parallax effect. I used javascript to allow me to add a class to the header so that it shrinks and changes the opacity on scrolling.

Here's the javascript, layout, and CSS:

```js
$(function () {
        $("#Page").scroll(function () {
            if ($("#Page").scrollTop() > 0)
                $("#header").addClass("scrolled");
            else
                $("#header").removeClass("scrolled");
        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="Page">
<div id="pre-header"></div>
<header id="header" class="">
    <div class="page-width">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav class="navigation-bar"> </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</div>

#Page {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    perspective: 100mm;
    perspective-origin: top right;
    position: static;
}

#header {
    padding-top: 34px;
    padding-bottom: 34px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 36px;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: background .8s;
}
```

My problem is that I need the header to still float at the top, even after Page has been scrolled.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We need the css as well

Comment: post css part ..

Comment: Fixed positioned elements will be positioned relative to the viewport.

Comment: For positioning we need the css part of this, thx in advance.

Comment: Use relative instead of fixed. Then you use top: 0 to pin the child to the top of the parent :)

Comment: Sounds like you really need to be absolutely positioning something inside a relatively positioned element.

Comment: @Stuart I tried that, but the header still goes off the top of the screen.

Comment: @pjones235 Can you clarify, is the header supposed to stay at the top at all times? Or is it supposed to be fixed at the top only when the parent element is in view?

Comment: @Huangism That is correct. It should stay on top at all times. All of the elements on the page are children of #Page.

Comment: @pjones235 remove `perspective: 100mm;` from your current code and it will work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/kjyxq6bq/

Comment: @Huangism Removing the perspective was definitely the solution I was looking for. The issue though, is that without the perspective, my background image element under #Page is enlarged. Plus, this brings a new issue, where the header and preheader divs both overlap the scrollbar, at least in Chrome.

Comment: @pjones235 Can you place the header outside of the perspective container? When you have perspective it basically sets a content container and position fix will not work properly inside of it

Comment: @Huangism That is another solution indeed, but it still causes the header to overlap the scrollbar.

Comment: @pjones235 because the header is position fixed it will overlap everything else on the page. You need to margin the content down or use padding to space out the area for the header.

Comment: @Huangism I'm confused. "Margin the content down"? If I add padding-right to the header, nothing happens. Even if I put 2000px, nothing.

Comment: @pjones235 the header overlaps due to position fixed, you need to push your site content down so it does not overlap. For example, if your header is 100px in height then put margin/padding top 100px for your content container